# iOS (ipad) split view controller

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a couple views that come before I want to show my split view, disclaimer and then login.  After successful login I want to segue to the the split view controller.  However I do not think there is a way in storyboards to segue to a split view controller.  How do I get from a normal view into my split view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes if it seems to cumbersome it may be an indication that one need to look at the problem from a different angle.

Assuming your goal is that of forcing the user to go through the login process, 
this is what I would do:

1. Have your splitView as the default view controller, added in the storyboard and loaded as the app starts
2. As soon as app is loaded, check for the existence of the user's credential. If you don't find any,
   present your login framework modally (full screen to cover any data underneath).
3. Once the user has successfully logged it, dismiss the modalVC and you will have the underlying splitVC  underneath ready for use.